# Exponential Power Series where Powers are Prime

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, reference-request, prime-numbers, power-series

I am looking for information in regards to a couple particular functions:

1)  $P(x)=\sum_{p\in\mathbb{P}}\frac{x^p}{p!}$

2)  $Q(x)=\sum_{p\not\in\mathbb{P}}\frac{x^p}{p!}$ (assuming $0, 1$ are included powers in the series...)

3)  $R(x)=\frac{1}{P(x)}$

4)  $S(x)=\frac{1}{Q(x)}$

I don't know if there is much literature on these, since I don't know if they are known, unknown, or what they are called.

Comment: This is an interesting question. I cannot answer it, but I can give you some cool looking plots of these functions. Would that help?

Comment: Yes, that would be great

Comment: someones know if they have any useful application ?

Comment: I don't believe I've found any useful applications, I've just been studying formal power series and lacunary series.  I thought, "what if" and posed the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comment chain on the question, the OP says that some plots would be helpful, so though I cannot answer this question, this is what I can say.

Though finding an analytic expression for these seems a monumental task, approximating them in the first several terms or so is quite easy. I evaluated each of these sums for $0\leq p\leq 41$, and we can estimate their accuracy by evaluating $err(x)=\left|e^x-\sum_{i=1}^{41} x^i/i!\right|$, and noting that if $|x|<4$, $err(x)$ is smaller than $10^{-10}$, so the following graphs can be judged as somewhat accurate.

[image: P(x)]

[image: Q(x)]

[image: R(x)]

[image: S(x)]

There are some interesting features. For one, $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ both have two roots. These are at $0$ and about $-2.301751$ for $P$, and about $-2.24203$ and $-1.05319$ for $Q$. We can also look at a plot of $P$ and $Q$ together with $e^x$:

[image: all three]

Note that there are intersections between $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ at about $2.06337$, $-0.789488$, and $-2.27713$. It is clear in the plot that $P(x)+Q(x)=e^x$.

Comment: I sort of designed $Q(x)$ to be the "complement" of $P$ in the expansion of $e^x$, so that last comment is perfect.  If we consider $P*(x)=P(x)=x^2/2$, then $P*$ is odd which kind of gives us the shape seen.  Nice plots...

Answer (score 3):

**trying to relate $P(x) = \sum_{p \in \mathcal{P}} \frac{x^p}{p!}$ to the logarithm of the Riemann zeta function**, I get :

$$P(x) = \sum_{p \in \mathcal{P}} \frac{x^p}{p!} = \frac{x}{(2 i \pi)^2}\int_{|u|=r} \frac{1}{(u-2x)(u-x)}\left( \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} (-\ln u)^{-s} \Gamma(s) \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(m)}{m} \ln \zeta(ms) ds\right) du$$
which I hope should be simplifiable.

let :
$$f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n z^n, \qquad\qquad g(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n!} z^n, \qquad \qquad F(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s}$$

(here $a_n = 1$ iff $n$ is prime, hence $F(s) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(m)}{m} \ln \zeta(ms)$)

by the [Cauchy integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula), for any $r < R$ the radius of convergence of $f$ :

$$a_n = \frac{n!}{2 i \pi}\int_{|u|=r} \frac{f(u)}{(u-z)^{n+1}} du$$

hence for any $|z| < r/2$ : $$g(z) = \frac{1}{2 i \pi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^n \int_{|u|=r} \frac{f(u)}{(u-z)^{n+1}} du = \frac{1}{2 i \pi}\int_{|u|=r} f(u) \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{(u-z)^{n+1}} du$$ $$ =\frac{z}{2 i \pi}\int_{|u|=r}  \frac{f(u)}{(u-2z)(u-z)} du$$

while from $n^{-s} \Gamma(s) = \int_0^\infty x^{s-1} e^{-nx} dx$ (extending $f(z)$ on $[0,1[$ by analytic continuation if necessary)  : $$\Gamma(s) F(s) = \int_0^\infty x^{s-1} f(e^{-x})dx$$

hence by [inverse Mellin transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform) : $$f(e^{-x}) = \frac{1}{2 i \pi}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} x^{-s} F(s) \Gamma(s) ds$$

and $$g(z) = \frac{z}{2 i \pi}\int_{|u|=r}  \frac{f(u)}{(u-2z)(u-z)} du = \frac{z}{(2 i \pi)^2}\int_{|u|=r} \frac{1}{(u-2z)(u-z)}\left( \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} (-\ln u)^{-s} F(s) \Gamma(s) ds\right) du = \ldots$$